# MySQL regexp for emoji / unicode

Tags: mysql, regex, unicode, mariadb, emoji

I want to search my database for any string which contains the Butterfly Emoji -  - using `regexp`.

For example

```
SELECT *
     FROM   `table`
     WHERE  `text`
     REGEXP ''
```

I'm using `REGEXP` because I might want to search for `Hello[[:space:]]world` or similar.

I get the error

> Got error 'nothing to repeat at offset 0' from regexp

This works:

```
SELECT *
     FROM   `table`
     WHERE  `text`
     LIKE   '%%'
```

But then I lose the ability to search for, say, `flying[[:space:]]`

My Collation is `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`. The database is 10.0.36-MariaDB

Comment: i advice you to read [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: If it uses utf-16 you should use a surrogate pair `'\uD83E\uDD8B'`,  otherwise use a codepoint `'\U0001F98B'`

Comment: @sln - The text provided in the Question is UTF-8 (hex `F09FA68B`), not utf-16.  Do not use `CHARACTER SET utf16`, nor `\u` codes.

Comment: It could be the encoding of the  MySQL source code text which means you have to use codepoints in the regex, which is always  a better idea. @RickJames - Regular expression source text are not represented with _byte code_. They represent _CODEPOINTS_ which disambiguates from the encoding source of both the regex source and target texts. This is typically processed  as the _Character Unit_ where as target encoding to  that unit is an opaque background task when the engine runs. `\uXXXX` `\u{XX}` `\x{XX}` are encoding independent _CODEPOINT_ constructs.

Comment: @sln - `\uD83E\uDD8B` is, to MySQL, 10 ascii bytes.  `\u` turns into `u`.  Note the absence of `\u` on https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-literals.html .  It _may_ be that the _client_ is interpreting codepoints.  `SELECT LENGTH('\uD83E\uDD8B');` --> 10.  See also `HEX()` and `CHAR_LENGTH()`.

Comment: @sln - The plot thickens.  `SELECT HEX('\U+1F98B');` --> `F09FA68B`.  (Note the added `+`.)  But `\U+0034` acts like an ascii string.  I gotta go scratch my head.

Comment: @RickJames - Ok, did little research. Num 1: If using version MySQL 8.0.4  or greater it uses the ICU regex engine. Num 2:  A back slash has to be  escaped to get a backslash to the engine. Num 3: Codepoint notation in ICU uses construct `\x{}`. Num 4: Have to use the `REGEXP` keyword. Num 5: sometimes the target is in utf-16, otherwise its utff-8/32. So, if you have a known mbcs,  convet it to 8/16/32 first. Putting that into place, try this.  `REGEXP '\\x{D83E}\\x{DD8B}'` or `REGEXP '\\x{1F98B}'`

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7c3c55c88b81996677e6271c0a0f51f5 I selected MySQL version 8. I don't think mariadb uses ICU engine like MySQL does for it's regex. So, good luck with that stuff ..

Answer (score 2):

Honestly I don't know why, but escaping your butterfly will give the desired output. (At least in my version, MariaDB 10.3.10, which gave the same error without escaping).

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `text` REGEXP '\\'
```

(note the double backslash, the first one is to escape the backslash within the string, yielding in the regular expression `\`)

Comment: Interesting. When I try that, it finds any text with the `?` character - as well as ones with the ``. Very strange! So your answer gets me closer - but itsn't quite right for me.

Comment: @TerenceEden: I can't reproduce the problem, see [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=182b6a4183397886f20833bc3aa4a9f8).

Comment: That fiddle is using MariaDB 10.3.11. I'm using 10.0.36. I suspect that's why.

Comment: I was using 10.3 as well, with the same error (although I got that error only on a regexp with a single butterfly, not with the `flying[[:space:]]` prefix). Maybe some server or connection setting? Or maybe PhpMyAdmin going wrong in my case...

Comment: This helped me on MariaDB 10.1.44 searching for `(foo||baz)`. Changing to `(foo|\\|baz)` performed the search as expected without errors. All character sets (client, database, etc.) were already set properly in each case.

Answer (score 0):

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'char%';
```

It sounds like you have not told MySQL what encoding the *client* is using for characters.  This is best done via the connection parameters, or via `mysqli_charset` (if using mysqli, not PDO).

Also, run this on your version:

```
SELECT 'ab' REGEXP '?';
```

I suspect it will give you the same error message.

Comment: Show Variables gives character_set_client utf8mb4 
character_set_connection utf8mb4 
character_set_database latin1 
character_set_filesystem binary 
character_set_results utf8mb4 
character_set_server latin1 
character_set_system utf8 
character_sets_dir /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ 

So it looks correct?
You're right about the error from the select statement.

Comment: Yes, that looks correct.  See "question mark" in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored